# C# MySQL claims a field is too long

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE patients 
(
  patient_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  last_name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(64),
  sex        CHAR(1),
  birth      DATE,
  death      DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (patient_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And here's the C#:

```
            MySqlCommand insertCom = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO patients(" +
                "last_name, first_name, sex, birth) VALUES" + 
                "('@lastName', '@firstName', '@sex', '@birthDate')",
                connection);

            /* ... */
            insertCom.Parameters.Add("@lastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            insertCom.Parameters.Add("@firstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            insertCom.Parameters.Add("@sex", MySqlDbType.Char, 1);
            insertCom.Parameters.Add("@birthDate", MySqlDbType.Date);

            insertCom.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = lastNameBox.Text; 
            insertCom.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = firstNameBox.Text;
            insertCom.Parameters["@sex"].Value = (sexBox.Text == "Male" ? 'M' : 'F');
            insertCom.Parameters["@birthDate"].Value = birthDatePicker.Text;
```

This is how I enter data directly in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO patients(last_name, first_name, sex, birth, death) 
VALUES
  ('DeLarge', 'Alexandra', 'F', '1975-12-02', NULL)
```

The above works and I wrote the C# code based on that. But the C# code produces this:
`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Data too long for column 'sex' at row 1`.
What gives?

Comment: My first thought is that the table expects latin1 or utf-8 data and is getting it in utf-16.  In utf-16, a CHAR(1) is a minimum of 2 bytes. In latin1, a CHAR(1) is 1 byte.  In utf-8, a CHAR(1) is a minimum of 1 byte.  However, I haven't used MySQL from .NET, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have single quotes around the parameter names. Try it like this instead:

```
MySqlCommand insertCom = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO patients(" +
            "last_name, first_name, sex, birth) VALUES" + 
            "(@lastName, @firstName, @sex, @birthDate)",
            connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, found your problem. I think your MySQL should be :

```
MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO patients(" +
                "last_name, first_name, sex, birth) VALUES" + 
                "(@lastName, @firstName, @sex, @birthDate)"
```

Because what you're trying to insert is `('DeLarge', 'Alexandra', 'F', '1975-12-02', NULL)`
But, your command dictates to insert : `('@lastName', '@firstName', '@sex', '@birthDate')`
And MySQL is catching that the value `'@sex'` is too big to fit in a single character

Take out the `'` from your command and let C# handle all the datatypes and formatting itself.